# Problema upload imagem com mais de 10mb primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces, upload, jsf-2.2, file-upload

Rapazes, estou passando por um problema bem chato e aparentemente simples e ainda não encontrei uma solução, será que alguém pode me ajudar?
Estou utilizando o upload do primefaces e ele simplesmente não faz o upload de arquivos maiores do que 10mb... Um arquivo de 9.9mb vai normal. =o

Gostaria de saber onde que eu altero para aumentar este limite?

Segue o código que estou utilizando:

```
<p:fileUpload multiple="false"  cancelLabel="Cancelar" label="Selecionar Brasão..." fileUploadListener="#{back.uploadArquivo}" mode="advanced" dragDropSupport="true" auto="false" 
         fileLimit="1" sizeLimit="51380224"    update="panel_grid_upload_arquivo, :growl" />
```

back:

```
  public void uploadArquivo(FileUploadEvent event) {
    DocumentoEntity arquivo = new DocumentoEntity();
    try {
        arquivo.setArquivo(IOUtils.toByteArray(event.getFile().getInputstream()));
        arquivo.setNomeArquivo(event.getFile().getFileName());
        arquivo.setNome(event.getFile().getFileName());
        this.arquivo = arquivo;
        exibirMensagemSucesso("Upload feito com sucesso", "O arquivo agora está associado ao documento");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        exibirMensagemErro("Ocorreu algum erro", "Ocorreu algum erro e o upload não pôde ser feito");
        LOGGER.error("Não realizou o upload do arquivo");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

meu web.xml está com essas configurações:

```
<filter>
<filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
<filter-class>org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
<servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>
```

Um arquivo maior do que 10mb nem chega no bean.
Desde já agradeço qualquer ajuda!

Comment: Qual servidor de aplicação você está usando?

Answer (score 2):

Eu descobri o problema após algumas horas... e era realmente bem simples. Esse erro aconteceu por causa do wildfly 8! Já que ele limita o tamanho máximo das requsições "post".
Eu tive que colocar max-post-size="50485760" no standalone.xml e agora funciona normal.

Ficou assim o trecho do standalone.xml:

```
<server name="default-server">
        <http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http" max-post-size="50485760"/>
        <host name="default-host" alias="localhost">
            <location name="/" handler="welcome-content"/>
            <filter-ref name="server-header"/>
            <filter-ref name="x-powered-by-header"/>
        </host>
    </server>
```